# Holomorphic structures on vector bundles over $\mathbb C\mathbb P^2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

It is known that every (topological) complex rank $2$ vector bundle over $\mathbb C\mathbb P^2$ admits holomorphic structures. A proof can be found in the book of [Okonek, Spindler, Schneider](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9781475714623) which is stated in the language of complex/algebraic geometry.

As a differential geometer I am struggling to understand this proof. Does someone know about a construction of $\bar\partial$-operators on complex rank $2$ vector bundles over $\mathbb C\mathbb P^2$ inducing holomorphic structures?

Comment: "As a geometer": you probably mean "as an analyst". Or are you suggesting that algebraic geometry is not a form of geometry?

Comment: Thank you for this remark! Of course algebraic geometry is a (beautiful) form of geometry. I was thinking more as a differential geometer. Changed that.